# Recover accidentally deleted Site Collection

Tags: 2007, site-collection, restore

In the process of cleaning up site collections of a Sharepoint 2007 MOSS farm that should be sub webs I *think* I 
accidentally deleted the main site collection of my farm (kill me now). This also happened while I was in the process of copying a site collection into a new sub web using DocAve (the delete was also with DocAve).

Don't worry I have backups and have restored to the 7th.

Before the delete my content db read about 260gb and 1 site. After the delete but before the restore my content db for that site read 400GB and 0 sites.

- My question is: I have lost an entire day of files and changes. Is
  there **ANY WAY** that I could recover them using the content db?

Answer (score 1):

if you have the Content DB backups you can get the files you deleted.
But you need a separate farm for this.
In lower farm, restore the Content DB, attach Content DB to Web App.from here you can recover all files, move from here to your main farm.

things to keep in mind, both farm should be same build level.

Why i suggest different farm, because you cannot attach same database twice in same farm. either you have to detach the current and attach the recovered.

Comment: How would you get to the files if it reports no site collections?

Comment: which farm you attached that content DB, if its in the same farm then it will show 0 site collection. you have to attach it to different farm.